# Suppress Leading Zeros in COBOL

Tags: cobol, leading-zero

I have tried looking this up online but I can't find anything that matches my situation. I need to suppress the leading zeros in the output but I can't get it working correctly. The number I need to suppress is the PR-PAY-RATE.

```
  ******************************************************************
   ID DIVISION.
      PROGRAM-ID. LAB5
      AUTHOR. asdf.
      DATE-WRITTEN. March 25, 2014.
      DATE-COMPILED. CURRENT-DATE.
  ******************************************************************
   ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
     INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
     FILE-CONTROL.
       SELECT PAYROLL-FILE ASSIGN TO PAYIN
       ORGANIZATION IS SEQUENTIAL.

   DATA DIVISION.
     FILE SECTION.
     FD PAYROLL-FILE.

  **** Payroll Record Length 360 characters ************************
   01  PAYROLL-RECORD.
       05  PR-EMPLOYEE-ID         PIC  X(07).
       05  PR-LAST-NAME           PIC  X(26).
       05  PR-FIRST-NAME          PIC  X(15).
       05  PR-DIVISION            PIC  X(10).
       05  PR-GROUP               PIC  X(10).
       05  PR-DEPARTMENT          PIC  X(10).
       05  PR-TITLE               PIC  X(20).
       05  PR-ADDRESS1            PIC  X(30).
       05  PR-ADDRESS2            PIC  X(30).
       05  PR-CITY                PIC  X(30).
       05  PR-STATE               PIC  X(2).
       05  PR-PROVINCE            PIC  X(20).
       05  PR-COUNTRY             PIC  X(20).
       05  PR-ZIP-POSTAL          PIC  X(09).
       05  PR-PAY1-STATUS         PIC  X(01).
           88  PR-STAT-ACTIVE         VALUE 'A'.
           88  PR-STAT-TERMINATED     VALUE 'T'.
           88  PR-STAT-RETIRED        VALUE 'R'.
           88  PR-STAT-DISCHARGED     VALUE 'D'.
       05  PR-START-DT            PIC  9(08).
       05  PR-TERM-DT             PIC  9(08).
       05  PR-TERM-REASON         PIC  X(30).
       05  PR-PAY-RATE            PIC  9(9)V99.
       05  PR-PAY-CYCLE           PIC  X(01).
           88  PR-HOURLY              VALUE 'H'.
           88  PR-BIWEEKLY            VALUE 'B'.
           88  PR-YEARLY              VALUE 'R'.
       05  PR-LAST-INCREASE-DT    PIC  9(08).
       05  PR-LAST-EVAL-DT        PIC  9(08).
       05  PR-LAST-EVAL-RATING    PIC  X(01).
           88  PR-RATE-A              VALUE 'A'.
           88  PR-RATE-B              VALUE 'B'.
           88  PR-RATE-C              VALUE 'C'.
           88  PR-RATE-D              VALUE 'D'.
           88  PR-RATE-N              VALUE 'N'.
       05  PR-BENEFIT-FLAG        PIC  X(01).
           88  PR-BENEFIT-YES         VALUE 'Y'.
           88  PR-BENEFIT-NO          VALUE 'N'.
       05  PR-MEDICAL-FLAG        PIC  X(01).
           88  PR-MEDICAL-YES         VALUE 'Y'.
           88  PR-MEDICAL-NO          VALUE 'N'.
       05  PR-DENTAL-FLAG         PIC  X(01).
           88  PR-DENTAL-YES          VALUE 'Y'.
           88  PR-DENTAL-NO           VALUE 'N'.
       05  PR-VISION-FLAG         PIC  X(01).
           88  PR-VISION-YES          VALUE 'Y'.
           88  PR-VISION-NO           VALUE 'N'.
       05  PR-BENEFIT-COST-YR     PIC  9(9)V99.
       05                         PIC  X(30).
  **** End of Payroll Record ***************************************


    WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
    01  WS-NAMED-MEMORY-LOCATIONS.
       05 EOF-SWITCH               PIC X        VALUE 'N'.
          88 EOF                                VALUE 'Y'.
          88 NOT-EOF                            VALUE 'N'.

       05 PAYROLL-COUNT            PIC 9(5).
       05 EMP-SELECTED             PIC 9(9)V99.
       05 TOTAL-PAY                PIC 9(9)V99.
       05 AVG-PAY                  PIC 9(9)V99.


  ******************************************************************
    PROCEDURE DIVISION.

    100-MAIN-PROGRAM.
       PERFORM 200-DISPLAY-SPLASH-PAGE.
       PERFORM 300-OPEN-FILES.
       PERFORM 400-READ-PAYROLL-FILE UNTIL EOF.
       PERFORM 700-END-PROGRAM.
       STOP RUN.

    200-DISPLAY-SPLASH-PAGE.
       DISPLAY '**************************************************'.
       DISPLAY '* asdf   ENTERPRISE TECHNOLOGIES LAB5            *'.
       DISPLAY '* asdf                                           *'.
       DISPLAY '* March 25, 2014                                 *'.
       DISPLAY '**************************************************'.

    300-OPEN-FILES.
       OPEN INPUT PAYROLL-FILE.

    400-READ-PAYROLL-FILE.
        READ PAYROLL-FILE
            AT END MOVE 'Y' TO EOF-SWITCH.

        IF EOF
            THEN PERFORM 700-END-PROGRAM.
        IF NOT-EOF
            PERFORM 500-PROCESS-PAYROLL-RECORDS
        END-IF.

     500-PROCESS-PAYROLL-RECORDS.

        ADD 1 TO PAYROLL-COUNT.

        IF PR-PAY1-STATUS = 'A' AND PR-PAY-CYCLE = 'B'
            THEN PERFORM 600-DISPLAY-PAYROLL-DATA.




     600-DISPLAY-PAYROLL-DATA.
       DISPLAY 'Employee ID        : ' PR-EMPLOYEE-ID.
       DISPLAY 'Employee First Name: ' PR-FIRST-NAME.
       DISPLAY 'Employee Last  Name: ' PR-LAST-NAME.
       DISPLAY 'Pay Status         : ' PR-PAY1-STATUS.
       DISPLAY 'Pay Cycle          : ' PR-Pay-Cycle.
       DISPLAY 'Pay Rate           : ' PR-Pay-Rate.
       DISPLAY '******************************************'.
        ADD 1 TO EMP-SELECTED.
        ADD PR-PAY-RATE TO TOTAL-PAY GIVING TOTAL-PAY.
        COMPUTE AVG-PAY = TOTAL-PAY / EMP-SELECTED.


     700-END-PROGRAM.


       DISPLAY 'Total Payroll Recs : ' PAYROLL-COUNT.
       DISPLAY 'Employees Selected : ' EMP-SELECTED.
       DISPLAY 'Total Pay          : ' TOTAL-PAY.
       DISPLAY 'Average Pay        : ' AVG-PAY.
       DISPLAY '******************************************'.
       DISPLAY '* End of LAB5                            *'.
       DISPLAY '******************************************'.
       CLOSE PAYROLL-FILE.
       STOP RUN.
```

Comment: Use `PIC ZZ,ZZZ,ZZ9.99` or if you don't want commas then `PIC Z(8)9.99`

Comment: I'm not sure where I need to put these. New to COBOL. I updated my code to show my latest changes. At the very bottom I need to suppress the leading zeros on the Total Payroll Recs, Employees Selected, Total Pay, and Average Pay. I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: In your `PAYROLL-RECORD` declaration, most fields have a `PIC` format. Change it there. [Simple example.](http://www.themainframes.com/jsppages/Cobol/Display.jsp)

Comment: @JohnC and the original....?

Comment: This question could use minimizing so that newcomers don't have to parse through its entirety.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In W-S

```
       05 FORMATTED-INTEGER          PIC Z(04)9.
       05 FORMATTED-CURRENCY         PIC Z(08)9.99.
```

in 700

```
   DISPLAY 'Total Payroll Recs : ' PAYROLL-COUNT.
```

becomes

```
   MOVE PAYROLL-COUNT TO FORMATTED-INTEGER.
   DISPLAY 'Total Payroll Recs : ' FORMATTED-INTEGER.
```

and follow the bouncing ball for the other display items.

MOVE TO /DISPLAY FORMATTED-CURRENCY if that's appropriate.

(and of course, identifier names are your choice). Also your choice to use a `PIC` of `Z(02),Z(03),Z(02)9.99.` if you want thousand-separator commas.

BTW - you call `700` twice - once at end-of-file, then again from the mainline. This will give you the display twice and probably an error too, sice you will be attempting to close a closed file.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much. Now I understand how to do it.